# How to fetch tensorflow version from tthe frozen model file

Tags: tensorflow

I have a  tensorflow frozen graph(.pb) file. How do I get the exact tensorflow version on which the model was trained on?

Answer (score 0):

From frozen graph(.pb) file alone, you can't get used tensorflow version.